# Model mapper map generic field

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, modelmapper

I am using ModelMapeer library and trying to add a custom mapping.
I have abstract entity:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity<ID extends Serializable> {
     private ID id;
}
```

and child entity

```
public class User extends AbstractEntity<UUID> {
     //fields
}
```

so I am trying to add custom mapping like this

```
this.typeMap(User.class, UserDetailsDto.class)
            .addMappings(mapper -> mapper.map(User::getId, UserDetailsDto::userId));
```

and getting this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.io.Serializable$ByteBuddy$lX3s11ID cannot be cast to class java.util.UUID
```

What do I need to change in a mapping(not entities) to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think `UserDetailsDto.userId` is `UUID` and `User.id` is `Serializable` Id. Both are not compatible.